# Yocto recipes not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto

I'm learning Yocto and to try it I'm following a very detailed [example](https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html).
When I try to build the image (`qt5.image`) it returns a couple of errors after parsing recipes:

```
$bitbake qt5-image
...
ERROR: No recipes available for:
  /home/dev/yocto/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_2019.07.bbappend
  /home/dev/yocto/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-omx_1.16%.bbappend
```

The error is pretty clear, but because those meta- are not mine, but downloaded from the official repository `git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi` I'm not sure why this error may happen.

Is there something I can fix by myself?

UPDATE:

Here the content of `bblayer.conf` I've adjusted the paths but it's the same file of the example linked above:

```
$ cat conf/bblayers.conf 
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-qt5 \
    ${HOME}/yocto/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
    ${HOME}/rpi/meta-rpi \
    "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the error message is telling you is that meta-raspberrypi layer is trying to modify recipes that it expects to exist in another layer. In this case the u-boot and gstreamer1.0-omx recipes come from "meta" (so the yocto/openembedded main layer).

You should check that your layers are all using the same branches (and are all up-to-date). I'm guessing that your meta layer (typically from poky git) is on some release branch and your meta-raspberrypi is using master. In that case the build would fail like yours does (e.g. gstreamer1.0-omx would be version 1.14.4 and the bbappend would look for another version).

Comment: mmm... I found something weird. The official Yocto docs (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7.1/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html) says: "The files available to you in that branch exactly match the repository's files in the 'warrior' development branch at the time of the Yocto Project yocto-2.7.1 release". The example checks-out the `warrior` branch, but perhaps `warrior` is not the same of `yocto-2.7.1`...

Comment: I think I need to find out how to force all layers to use `yocto-2.7.1` only

Comment: It seems it was enough to check out the `warrior` branch of the git repository (instead of the default `master`).

Comment: Peculiar; the pathname on my host (poky / 'warrior') meta/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_2019.01.bb ; once i manually renamed it to meta/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_2019.07.bb, this error vanished (similarly for the rem errors)

Comment: @kaiwan the errors may have disappeared... but that's still a very wrong way to fix the issue

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I do agree; but, in the interest of moving forward i did so; in the situation i faced, what would be the 'correct' way?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, what I did is to checkout meta-raspberrypi with branch corresponding to the poky branch:

1. `git clone -b warrior git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky`
2. `cd poky`
3. `git clone -b warrior git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi`
4. `source oe-init-build-env`
5. Add layer to conf/bblayers.conf
6. Change MACHINE in conf/local.conf
7. `bitbake rpi-basic-image`

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure 'meta-raspberrypi' is included in bblayers.conf file. You can check this layer included in

```
build-*/conf/bblayers.conf
```

If it is not included, add this layer into bbpath in bblayers.conf and rebuild it.

If it's still available could you please send the complete logs for the error?